# Fastest way of finding nearest pixel in relation to another pixel while satisying conditions. OpenCV Numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, opencv, optimization

I am looking for the fastest way that I can read an image in, specify a pixel, and find the nearest pixel to that pixel given my conditionals.

I originally had a nested loop that would go through each pixel in my 2D image array, check for conditional, than add it to a new array. Than go through the new array and do the distance calculations on each member. 
That was terribly slow, and has a time complexity of n^2 I believe.

I am now doing the distance calculations, and sorting the array by that, which is quite fast when using numpy. But then I still have to go through that 2D sorted array with a nested loop to check for conditionals, which again is a time complexity of n^2. It does save some time though because I can normally find the pixel I am looking for sooner in the array.

```
img2=cv2.imread(filename)
distances = numpy.sqrt((img2[:,:] - currR) ** 2 + (img2[:,:] - currC) ** 2)
nearest = numpy.sort(distances)
for row in range(nearest.shape[0]):
    for col in range(nearest.shape[1]):
        if pixelInLine[row*imgCol + col] == 0  and colorCheck(row,col) and numpy.any(img2[row, col] != 0):
            #do my calculations on the specified pixel. and break the loop
```

I am unsure how I can optimize this further, and potentially lower the time complexity from n^2 to something more reasonable.

Comment: If you state what your conditions are, it may be possible to vectorize it all. By the way, rather than testing if sqrt(X) is less than 10, leave out the expensive sqrt() and just test if X is less than 100.

Comment: Ahhh my bad, I didnt think the conditionals were pertinent to the solution besides the fact that they existed. pixelInLine is used to tell us which pixels we have visited already previously in the program, colorCheck is a function that checks the image at the specific pixel to see if that pixel is the color we want, and the numpy.any part excludes black pixels. I am a little confused by what you mean with your last sentence. What do you mean testing is sqrt is less than 10? Where do I do that. Thank you for the response.

Comment: You calculate the distances as the sqrt() of two squared numbers. I am suggesting you don't take the sqrt().

Comment: I can't help feeling you might get a much better answer if you gave a sample image, described your algorithm and showed the results you expect.

Comment: Provide an example image and expected output. That said, this is a pretty simple computation and it shouldn't be too restrictive to just find all pixels matching the condition and then search on the set of all pixels matching the condition. You can do this in a vectorized way instead of nesting loops and searching a bunch of extra pixels.

Comment: Also relevant questions that can change the answer: do you expect your conditionals to be very restrictive (only 1% of the pixels are the right color) or on the contrary very broad (e.g. you just remove black and 99% of the pixels fulfill you conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Go spiraling away from the target pixel and stop as soon as you meet the "conditionals". For convenience, you can use a square spiral (in fact nested squares).

If the distance is Euclidean, the cost of the search will be between 2d² and 4d² where d is the distance to the hit.

Comment: @Program232323: of course, you don't precompute the distances, this is a big waste.